# SQL Query to find products with consecutive increase in their prices

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with history data of product prices, which fluctuates every minute.

This is one day's snapshot:

```
ProductName | Iteration | Price | Date
----------------------------------------------
A           |    1      | 10    | 1st Feb 2019 12:01 AM
B           |    1      | 10    | 1st Feb 2019 12:01 AM
C           |    1      | 10    | 1st Feb 2019 12:01 AM
A           |    2      | 12    | 1st Feb 2019 12:02 AM
B           |    2      | 9     | 1st Feb 2019 12:02 AM
C           |    2      | 15    | 1st Feb 2019 12:02 AM
A           |    3      | 15    | 1st Feb 2019 12:03 AM
B           |    3      | 9     | 1st Feb 2019 12:03 AM
C           |    3      | 14    | 1st Feb 2019 12:03 AM
A           |    4      | 14    | 1st Feb 2019 12:04 AM
B           |    4      | 11    | 1st Feb 2019 12:04 AM
C           |    4      | 14    | 1st Feb 2019 12:04 AM
```

And I want to find out the product name (for each day) which shows consecutive increase in it's price in consecutive iterations, along with the number of occurrence.

In the given sample data above, price of product A increased consecutively.
I want the output like below:

```
ProductName | Occurrence
------------------------
A           | 3
```

I tried self joining like below:

```
SELECT A.ProductName, A.Iteration as LastIteration, B.Iteration  as CurrentIteration, A.Price as LastPrice, B.Price as CurrentPrice FROM
ProductDetails (NOLOCK) A
INNER JOIN ProductDetails (NOLOCK) B ON A.ProductName = B.ProductName AND B.Iteration=A.Iteration+1 AND B.Price>A.Price AND Convert(Date, A.Date)=Convert(Date, B.Date)
```

But this does not give me all the consecutive occurrences.
Can somebody help?

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) & [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions for this.  Find the boundaries where the price does *not* increase.  Then use this to define groups -- and aggregate to find the length of the groups.

The following gets all the durations of periods of increasing prices:

```
select productname, count(*) as num_prices,
       min(price) as first_price, max(price) as last_price
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_price < price then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by productname order by iteration) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(price) over (partition by productname order by iteration) as prev_price
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by productname, grp
having count(*) > 1;
```

If you want the largest, you can add:

```
select top (1) with ties . . .
. . .
order by row_number() over (partition by productname order by count(*) desc)
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what exactly this code does?